# How can I prevent expect from ignoring new lines?

Tags: expect

In my current, draft script, the `show` command output is fine, but once I hit the "conf" commands, the output is pressed together. How do I fix this?

```
set timeout 20
spawn ssh -l manager 192.168.41.10.10
expect "manager@192.168.10.10's password:"
send "admin\r"
expect "Press any key to continue"
send "j"
log_file hp.log
send "show vlan 10\r"
expect "newsw*"
send "conf\r"
expect "newsw*(config)"
send "\r"
send "vlan 45\r"
expect "newsw*"
send "tagged 3\r"
send "exit\r"
send "exit\r"
```

The is what the log looks like for the "conf" section and related commands. The output is running together. You can see a piece of the "show vlan 45" at the end.

```
newswitch# confnewswitch(config)# vlan 45newswitch(vlan-45)# tagged 3newswitch(vlan-45)# exitnewswitch(config)# exitnew$ Status and Counters - VLAN Information - VLAN 45

      VLAN ID : 45
      Name : VLAN45
```

Here is the proper / desired output. I would think that it would look like this:

```
newswitch# 
conf
newswitch(config)# vlan 45
newswitch(vlan-45)# tagged 3
newswitch(vlan-45)# exit
newswitch(config)# exit
newswitch$ show vlan 45 ....and so forth
```

Comment: I don't understand the bit in the middle: does that show up in the log file or on the screen?  Can you improve the formatting of your question. Formatting hint: you can separate code blocks with a normal paragraph or with a non-indented empty HTML comment.

Comment: Ah yes. I have put the run-on message(s) in brackets now.

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if this is a consequence of using `\r` in the send commands. Try using `\n` instead

Comment: I know , it's strange. I have tried /n and /r and multiple, combinations, etc. Frustrated.

Comment: Try `od -c logfile` and check if there are any invisible characters separating the lines.

Comment: Not familiar with od -c but here is a snippet of output.

0001160  \n      \n  \n   n   e   w   s   w   i   t   c   h   #       c
0001200   o   n   f   n   e   w   s   w   i   t   c   h   (   c   o   n
0001220   f   i   g   )   #       v   l   a   n       4   5   n   e   w
0001240   s   w   i   t   c   h   (   v   l   a   n   -   4   5   )   #
0001260       t   a   g   g   e   d       3   n   e   w   s   w   i   t
0001300   c   h   (   v   l   a   n   -   4   5   )   #       e   x   i
0001320   t   n   e   w   s   w   i   t   c   h   (   c   o   n   f   i

Comment: hm, no line feeds or carriage returns in there. Mysterious.